# Skeletal animation 3d models

Tags: c++, animation, models, skeletal-animation

I'm building a skeletal animation system. My goal is to make it as efficient as I can.

Is there a place where I can download some 3d models (preferably from real games) So I could see if my system animates them efficiently?

The current model I'm testing on has 12500 faces overall and 57 bones. My FPS drops from 60 when there are 10~ animated instances of it running. I don't know if it's okay or bad.

Any other help and tips for benchmarking my system will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The question as it stands is "where can I find 3D models". Questions about where free assets can be found are [specifically off-topic](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Google has lots of results for "free 3D character rig"; are they not good enough? Perhaps you're getting caught on an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and actually intended to ask "*what complexity of a model should my skeletal animation support to be attractive to modern game developers*". Could you explain your motivation for making the animation system?

Comment: The models I get from googling are simply trash. Most of them don't even work. Some of them are "rigged" but don't really have animations, just bones, which isn't what I need.
Also, I'm trying to make a system that will produce efficient results with rather "standard and below" 3d models (cs:go, league of legends, definitely not anything Crysis-like / Assassin's Creed / most modern video game graphics)